# Passing array of XmlRpcStruct in XML-RPC throws error in C#

Tags: c#, xml-rpc

I am using XML_RPC v2.5.0 for .Net to make few calls to web service to send product data. All calls are working OK except one scenario. I am sending product data to the web service that is expected to be in the below format(Format is defined in PhP language) -

```
$order['products'][] = ['sku', 'quantity']
```

I am using the below code to pass this data -

```
XmlRpcStruct dic = new XmlRpcStruct();
DataTable dt1 = GetData();
XmlRpcStruct[] prod = new XmlRpcStruct[dt1.Rows.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   prod[i] = new XmlRpcStruct();
   prod[i].Add("sku", dt1.Rows[i][0].ToString());
   prod[i].Add("quantity", dt1.Rows[i][1].ToString());
}
dic.Add("products", prod);
object orderID = proxy.SubmitOrder(dic, custID, accessKey);
```

The above code works when there is only 1 row in the data table dt1 and I get the orderID successfully. However, if there are more than 1 records in the data table, I am getting an exception as  -

> A parameter is of, or contains an instance of, type CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcStruct which cannot be mapped to an XML-RPC type

I think I am missing something silly here. Please help and let me know what mistake I am doing here.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code written above works OK. The issue with me was passing a null value to one of the other parameters when passing an array and hence the issue.

Answer (score 0):

move this line of code

```
`dic.Add("products", prod);`
```

to the last line within your loop to make it work b/c it currently adds only single item to your dictionary.

The other mistake what I think the 'dic' and 'prod' object was not a List.

your code suppose to be:

```
`List<XmlRpcStruct> dic = new List<XmlRpcStruct>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
       List<XmlRpcStruct> prod = new List<XmlRpcStruct>();
       prod.Add("sku", dt1.Rows[i][0].ToString());
       prod.Add("quantity", dt1.Rows[i][1].ToString());
       dic.Add("products", prod); //this line might be a culprit
    }

    object orderID = proxy.SubmitOrder(dic, custID, accessKey);`
```

Comment: Haroon..I just edited my question with the correct code. please see, the error still persists.

Comment: The code I wrote is working perfectly OK. I had an issue with a NULL value in the field and now it is working. Thanks for your help. BY the way, List<> wont work and throw an error as "A parameter is of, or contains an instance of, type List which cannot be mapped to an XML-RPC type"